# files\folders appear twice in Aptana Studio's Project Explorer

Tags: aptana, aptana3

For some reason many files of various types and even folders appear twice in Aptana's Project Explorer on my setup.
In each such couple, one of the items has a small `+` next to it, and one does not.

How come? How can I fix this?

Comment: What type of files (PHP/JS/Python/etc) or projects do you see the error in? Also do you have other plugins installed besides Aptana Studio?

Comment: @Michael - it's a vanilla copy of Aptana, no plugins. It's a django based Web project that I worked on using eclipse and shifted to Aptana using the Import Project\General\Existing Folder as New Project

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to use Custom View... from the drop-down menu in Project Explorer and uncheck Content > Local Filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

While I've never seen this, it sounds like a bug, perhaps particular to your setup. I would suggest filing more details at http://jira.appcelerator.org.

Comment: [Opened](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4638)